# External SQL Server access in MVC 3 + Entity Framework for query-only

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, connection-string, dbcontext

I'm devoloping a system using MVC 3 with EF 4. In this system, I need to lookup some information that already exists in an external database.

Saving me project's information on *my* database is OK. I defined my Models on it and let DbContext create the tables on my server.

The problem is when I try to query some data from the external database. I've added the connection string in the properly place on `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExtDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=path.to.server;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=2;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is it possible to just create some queries to this server on my project without the overload of recreating all the Models from this external database? I know I can recover this connection string on my code by using the command `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExtDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString`, but how can I create a connection and instantiate my queries?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** @rouen called my atention I didn't explicitly said the databases are differents. They do **not** share the same schema! The external database is the output of a report; so, I need to traverse it on my project to import the relevant lines to the local database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use standard ADO.NET. Use the SqlConnection and SqlCommand classes.

ADO.NET Examples on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is the remote database schemantically identical as your local ? If yes, you can pass connectionstring to constructor of ObjectContext/DbContext, and it will use that database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: No, the remote database has nothing to do with local. Think of it as a result of a report, which I will query over to find the relevant parts to import to my system.